# How to show errors from two beans

Tags: grails

How can I show errors from two beans (second one being a command object) in one list?

I can do this:

```
<g:hasErrors beans="${bookInstance}">
<g:renderErrors bean="${bookInstance}" as="list" />
</g:hasErrors>
<g:hasErrors beans="${myCmdObject}">
<g:renderErrors bean="${myCmdObject}" as="list" />
</g:hasErrors>
```

but it gives me two lists. I want to do something like this:

```
<g:hasErrors beans="${bookInstance, myCmdObject}">
<g:renderErrors bean="${bookInstance, myCmdObject}" as="list" />
</g:hasErrors>
```

which will give me one list. Is there a nice way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can use the `model` attribute described [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/renderErrors.html). It takes in a map and will render the errors of all the entries in that map. The same is true for [hasErrors](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/hasErrors.html).

Try:

```
<g:hasErrors beans="[bookInstance:bookInstance, myCmdObject:myCmdObject]">
    <g:renderErrors beans="[bookInstance:bookInstance, myCmdObject:myCmdObject]" as="list" />
</g:hasErrors>
```

Comment: just some correction: the  <g:renderErrors bean="[bookInstance:bookInstance, myCmdObject:myCmdObject]" as="list" /> should have an "s" in the word bean

Comment: In Grails (at least in 2.5.X) there is no such "beans" tag. The correct tag to use is "model".